# Instaling ThingsBoard on Docker with PostreSql

Tags: docker, postgresql

So I'm trying to install ThingsBoard using Docker on a MacBook Pro.

I'm following the instrutions on (https://hub.docker.com/r/thingsboard/tb-postgres/)

After the instalation I need to configure the Docker image of thingsboard to use an external database from PostgreSql.

Anyone who can help me how to do it? I read some documentation and they say to change the `.env` and `tb.env` file...but can't find these files on my disk.

Answer (score 0):

The image you reference has a preinstalled Postgres database inside, so no need for external one.

If you want separate container with database, you can follow instructions on the tool's [git repository](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/docker). The .env file is located [there](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/docker/.env) and this is what they mean by the `.env` file to edit, to choose which database should be deployed.

Other than that, to connect this container to a standalone database, you'd have to tweak it's internal configuration.

Comment: So basically installing ThingsBoard on Docker, it will use the default PostreSQL database preinstalled named "PostgreSql 11". What i want is just create a new server with a new database, inside PostgreSql and connect myTB to that database. Do you know how to do this??

Comment: not really, but have a look at their `docker-compose` files, they may give you a clue, as there services are somewhat separated.